# How to capture a User in the create action for sending a msg?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to implement functionality where User A can send a message to User B. Say User A is viewing User B's profile and clicks on the Send Message link, how can I make sure that only User B will receive the message. In other words in the Create action how can I capture User B? I am able to capture User B in the new action but not in the create action. Here is what I have so far:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @message = Message.new
      @recipient = User.find_by_identifier!(params[:id])
  end

  def create
      @message = Message.new(params[:message])
      @message.recipient = @recipient
      @message.sender = current_user
      if @message.save
        flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
        redirect_to messages_path(:mailbox=>:sent)
      else
        render :action => :new
      end
  end
end
```

So the Send Message link passes in the params of User B for the new action. So `@recipient` in the new action is User B and I am able to display User B's name and picture. But `@recipient` is nil in the create action. How can I ensure that @recipient in the create action is User B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field to your submit message form that is the recipient user ID.

In your form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => @recipient.id %>
```

This way, your params will have the recipient and you'll create the new message with the recipient info.

It also depends on what your route for create action is. If you have the `recepient_id` available in the route, just use it again as you did in the `new` action.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables in controllers are only good for one request - `@recipient` isn't set from `new` any more during the `create` request.

So look it up again! Make sure `:id` is still present in your HTTP parameters, and just do `@message.recipient = User.find(params[:id])`.